# how to fix algolia firebase extension auto sync problem

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I have integrated my Firebase project with Algolia search engine. However, I am facing an issue where any updates or deletions made to the documents in the designated collection are not reflected in the search results. Can someone suggest a solution to address this problem?

i have enabled auto sync on the plugin but there is no chnge